# Firebase not firebase not respons : Transfer-Encoding: chunked < * Connection #1 to host fcm.googleapis.com left intact

Tags: php, firebase, ssl, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

i want to send  push notification for all of them user install application  with Firebase Admin PHP SDK library in drupal 8 in the request time i have below error.

my code:

```
$messaging = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount(__DIR__ . '/file .json')->withEnabledDebug()->withProjectId('project name')->createMessaging();

$config = AndroidConfig::fromArray([
  'ttl' => '3600s',
  'priority' => 'normal',
  'notification' => [
    'title' => '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    'body' => '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
    'icon' => 'stock_ticker_update',
    'color' => '#f45342',
    'sound' => 'default',
  ],
]);
$title = 'My Notification Title';
$body = 'My Notification Body';
$imageUrl = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/';
$notification = Notification::fromArray([
  'title' => $title,
  'body' => $body,
  'image' => $imageUrl,
]);

$topic = 'b-topic';
$message = CloudMessage::withTarget('topic', $topic)
  ->withAndroidConfig($config)
  ->withNotification($notification);
$messaging->send($message);
```

When I activate the log :

```
Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
 Trying 216.58.208.106...
 TCP_NODELAY set
 Connected to oauth2.googleapis.com (216.58.208.106) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering http/1.1
 successfully set certificate verify locations:
 CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
Your question couldn’t be submitted
 SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
 ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
 Server certificate:
 subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=upload.video.google.com
 start date: Oct 20 18:07:22 2020 GMT
 expire date: Jan 12 18:07:22 2021 GMT
 subjectAltName: host "oauth2.googleapis.com" matched cert's 
 .googleapis.com"
 issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1
 SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.4 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.4.11
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 1209

* upload completely sent off: 1209 out of 1209 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 < Vary: X-Origin < Vary: Referer < Date: Sat, 07 Nov
    2020 07:14:17 GMT < Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2 < Cache-Control: private < X-XSS-Protection: 0 <
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < Alt-Svc: h3-Q050=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443" ;
    ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443" ;
    ma=2592000,quic=":443" ; ma=2592000; v="46,43" < Accept-Ranges: none < Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding <
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked < * Connection #0 to host oauth2.googleapis.com left intact * Trying 64.233.177.95... *
    TCP_NODELAY set * Trying 2a00:1450:400e:800::200a... * TCP_NODELAY set * Immediate connect fail for
    2a00:1450:400e:800::200a: Network is unreachable * Trying 2a00:1450:400e:806::200a... * TCP_NODELAY set * Immediate
    connect fail for 2a00:1450:400e:806::200a: Network is unreachable * Trying 2a00:1450:400e:809::200a... * TCP_NODELAY
    set * Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:400e:809::200a: Network is unreachable * Trying
    2a00:1450:400e:80d::200a... * TCP_NODELAY set * Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:400e:80d::200a: Network is
    unreachable * Connected to fcm.googleapis.com (64.233.177.95) port 443 (#1) * ALPN, offering http/1.1 * successfully
    set certificate verify locations: * CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CApath: /etc/ssl/certs * SSL
    connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1 * Server certificate: *
    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=edgecert.googleapis.com * start date: Oct 20
    18:13:46 2020 GMT * expire date: Jan 12 18:13:46 2021 GMT * subjectAltName: host "fcm.googleapis.com" matched
    cert's "fcm.googleapis.com"  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=GTS CA 1O1 * SSL certificate verify ok.>
    POST /v1/projects/pj name/messages:send HTTP/1.1
    Host: fcm.googleapis.com
    User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.4 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.4.11
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    authorization: Bearer
"token"
    Content-Length: 396

* upload completely sent off: 396 out of 396 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 < Vary: X-Origin < Vary: Referer < Date: Sat, 07
        Nov 2020 07:14:18 GMT < Server: ESF < Cache-Control: private < X-XSS-Protection: 0 < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < Alt-Svc: h3-Q050=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443" ;
        ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443" ; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443" ;
        ma=2592000,quic=":443" ; ma=2592000; v="46,43" < Accept-Ranges: none < Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding <
Transfer-Encoding: chunked < * Connection #1 to host fcm.googleapis.com left intact
```

i conected to google SDK but when i cant conected to  fcm.googleapis.com and error to Transfer-Encoding .i try to ssl domain but not work again.

Comment: I don't see any error here. Transfer-Encoding chunked is not an error. The server also results with a status code of 200, i.e. success.

Comment: this Error :
Transfer-Encoding: chunked < * Connection #1 to host fcm.googleapis.com left intact
  and not work FCM

Comment: Again, __this is not an error__. This is part of the __successful__ HTTP response, i.e. the part which starts with `HTTP/1.1 200 Ok < ...` And *"not work FCM"* is not a useful error description.